# Azure Pipelines agent credentials

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When installing Azure Pipelines agent, using Integrated authentication method - in case I'm logged in to machine with my domain user and installing the agent windows service to run using NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, is that mean the agent will run on the machine using my domain credentials?

Thanks!

Comment: When you configure your Azure agent Windows service to run under a specific account for example `NT\Local System` then the agent will run with those permissions regardless of the fact which account you used in order to install the agent. Every action you perform for pipelines will be executed with these permissions.

Comment: @GeralexGR you should post this as an Answer, I'd vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your Azure agent Windows service to run under a specific account for example `NT\Local System` then the agent will run with those permissions regardless of the fact which account you used in order to install the agent. Every action you perform for pipelines will be executed with these permissions on the machine that agent runs.

[image]